# If G = (V,A) a connected graph, planar, proof that... $q\leq 3p -6$

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

sorry, just started to see graphs, but how can you proof that,

If G = (V,A) a connected graph, plannar, with *p* verices and *q* edges.

Proof that...

$q\leq 3p -6$

Any help or orientation would be deeply appreciated. Thank you!

(I made a drawing where p = 3, but I doubt this is the correct answer...):

[image]

Comment: "We will call $n_i$ the number of vertices of value $i$." What does this mean? It isn't even used in the theorem.

Comment: Later on they write another thing to prove which uses $n_{i}$ You are right, I will remove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Assume that $G$ is a maximal planar graph. By maximality of $G$, we can not add more edges without destroying planarity. Observe that each face in this maximal planar graph is a triangle. Otherwise, we could always add diagonal edges (convince yourself that this is true; draw a few planar graphs). Now, denote $p$ as the number of vertices, $q$ as the number of edges and $f$ as the number of faces in $G$. And every edge bounds two faces, hence $2q=3f$. Use Euler's formula $p-q+f=2$, and the other observations and you quickly get the upper bound.

Comment: Thank you so much, David! I shall try to do that : )

Comment: You are welcome! If you still have problems, write a comment and I'd be happy to go into more details.